# Failed to connect to PostgreSQL with Azure AD User via Azure data studio

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-postgresql

I am following this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/postgresql/howto-configure-sign-in-aad-authentication#migrating-existing-postgresql-users-to-azure-ad-based-authentication) and I have added Azure AD User to my Azure PostgreSQL. When I use admin user I can connect to the server but when I change to use Azure AD-based authentication, it always got error `Token get failed ...`. I think I'm lost, please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the reason because you didn't provide details about how you configure the AAD-based authentication.

But there is a new, simpler way to sign-in with AAD account.

Please refer to [New, simpler way to sign-in to Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Single Server using Azure AD](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-for-postgresql/new-simpler-way-to-sign-in-to-azure-database-for-postgresql/ba-p/1247272).

You just need to configure the Azure AD Administrator in the Azure Portal.

[image]

**Remember** that when you try to sign in in Azure Data Studio, you need to specify the **username** as **`AADuser@{your AAD domain}.com@{PostgreSQL server name}`**

[image]